# How to pass arguments to anonymous functions using pipe operator?

Tags: elixir

I am playing around with Elixir. Just wondering is it possible to pass arguments using pipe `|>` operator to anonymous functions.  Here is what I meant.

```
a = [1,2,3] #=> [1,2,3]
m = fn ([h|t]) -> [ h*h | m.(t) ] end #=> head squared and call m with tail.  Not sure how to use & shortcut for this.
m.(a) #=> [1,4,9]
a |> m #=> undefined function m/1 (understood. Arity is 1)
a |> m.(&1) #=> unhandled &1 outside of capture
```

Comment: `m = fn ([h|t]) -> [ h*h | m.(t) ]` will give an error

Answer (score 3):

You can pass anonymous functions to pipeline for example,

```
 m = fn(x) -> x * x end # Function<6.50752066/1 in :erl_eval.expr/5>
 3 |> m.() # 9
```

It seems like you are making a recursive call inside a anonymous function which is not possible. Line `m = fn ([h|t]) -> [ h*h | m.(t) ]` will lead to error on execution.

To make this work, you can either pass the same function as another argument, or you can use a named function which I would prefer since it looks more clear to me.

```
m = fn ([h|t],my_func) -> [ h*h | my_func.(t) ] end
a |> m.(m)
```

Answer (score 2):

The error results from the base condition where there is no argument left, it cannot be partitioned to [H|T].

```
a = [1,2,3] #=> [1,2,3]
m = fn
  ([],_) -> []
([h|t], fun) -> [ h*h | fun.(t, fun)]
end

b = m.(a,m)

IO.inspect b #=> [1, 4, 9]
```

**UPDATE**

Other difference is that function's itself is unknown in itself, thus passing it as argument (fun) is required.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this way

```
a |> (&m.(&1))
```